# Sitecore - Rich Text Editor field is not saving information but instead just copying old information back to the field

Tags: asp.net, .net, sitecore, rich-text-editor

We are using Sitecore.NET 5.3.1 (rev. 071114) and we found out a problem. When we are trying to change information in a Rich Text Editor field on the Master database and save the information, this information is not stored and instead the old information appears back into the RTE field. I have been trying this on the Web database on which this is not happening. However, changing this information on the web database feels useless because a publish will just change every information that does not correspond to the data in the Master database in which i just can't edit this field. So I'm having big trouble at this point since this is for one of our bigger customers and they really want this fixxed asap. We (Estate Internet) already have had an open ticket for this problem, but never got the solution. Hope that someone here knows what the problem may be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> We (Estate Internet) already have had an open ticket for this problem, but never got the solution.

If you have opened ticket on the support portal, you can always reopen it by adding new comment in the ticket - or create a new one, if you do not have its ID.
The problem you described seems to be related to Shared Fields mechanism, and its fixing requires additional investigation on your database.

Comment: Okay thanks for the answer. I will solve this issue by creating a new template and just adjusting my code. I tested this and it worked!